# Nested sets getting all users which are a leafs

Tags: laravel, eloquent, nested-lists, nested-sets

I am using Node/Baum for my user types. When a user registers they can have assigned to them a user type that is not a leaf but they would not be able to get access until they go further down and set their user type a leaf.

Example: if I have the category of Fruits(Banana, Apple, Pear) and Animals (Cat, Dog, Rabbit), my user can have a user type of 'Fruit' assigned but until they chose the subcategory like 'Banana' they won't get access.

I need to be able to query my DB for all the users that have a user type that is  a leaf. Since I also allow them to register with user types that are not leaves I need to find a way to differentiate between the two types. Node/Baum comes with a method `isLeaf()` but that won't work on a collection.

How can I do this query?

I have the User Model that is linked to a UserType Model. My UserType Model is a Node/Baum extension.

```
$users = User::
        whereHas('user_type', function($q) {  
        // where user_type is leaf ???  
        })  
   ->get();
```

I must specify that Node/Baum uses a `right` and `left` column to deal with the nested sets. Testing if a record is a leaf is done by `right - left == 1`. How can I do this in a query while using Eloquent?